# Execute Code after all Android Instrumentation tests have finished

Tags: android, testing, junit, automation, instrumentation

I have a large set of Android Instrumentation (Espresso, Robotium, UI Automator) test cases spread over many different test classes.

After every test case in every test class has finished, I want to execute some piece of code.

Has anybody every tried this? Tipps are greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's a reason this isn't a great idea-  if your tests crash, there's no guarantee that it will be called ever.  As the usual thing to put here is cleanup code, that would be bad.  Its usually a better idea to do cleanup of the previous run before running the tests the next time just to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is a good point you are making there.
Then my question would be how can I execute a piece of code only once before testing starts?

Comment: You could still catch the exception thrown by a failing test and react on it, making it possible to trigger some action in case of a failing test, right?